# Does Arduino needs specific function command to connected in bluetooth?

Tags: java, android, arduino, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

I'm trying to connect android device with Arduino and receive the sensor value.
I've found the sample codes of Arduino-Android bluetooth examples but none of them worked in bluetooth connection. Mostly, the android device can't scan the arduino and the only examples that found arduino can't connect with it. Below is the bluetooth connection with butoon click and trying to receive the value :

```
Button btnConnect = findViewById(R.id.btnConnect); // trying to connect
    btnConnect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Button Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            if (bt.getServiceState() == BluetoothState.STATE_CONNECTED) {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Trying to Connect", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DeviceList.class);
                startActivityForResult(intent, BluetoothState.REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE);


            }
        }
    });

    bt.setOnDataReceivedListener(new BluetoothSPP.OnDataReceivedListener() {

        TextView dist = findViewById(R.id.data);

        public void onDataReceived(byte[] data, String message) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Data receiving available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.d("Y message : ", message);
            Log.d("Y data : ", String.valueOf(data));

            String[] array = message.split(",");

            dist.setText(array[0].concat("cm"));

        }
    });
```

And I found out that the startActivityForResult has deprecated, and wonder this cause the disconnection. I'm not very familiar with android programming so any help would be very welcome. Thanks in advance.